# cross-domain flash movie loaded with swfobject won't play on first page load

Tags: javascript, flash, cross-domain, swfobject

I'm using SWFObject v2.2, and loading a swf from a different domain (Amazon S3) to (ideally) play back on the page.

Here's my page on domain A: http://cssquirrel.com/testcases/swfobject/

Relevant parts: There's a div with the id "movie", and demo.js (which is called in the page) does the following:

```
swfobject.embedSWF("https://s3.amazonaws.com/media.anvilcorp.com/videos/safety.swf", "movie", "640", "480", "10.0.0");
```

I've created the crossdomain file and placed it on domain B where the SWF file is hosted. The file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="cssquirrel.com" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

When I load the page for the first time, I've confirmed that it loads the swf file, but it never starts playing.

On a second page load, the file starts playing (from the cache). Reloading after clearing the cache and it again won't play back on the first load.

I've tried manually triggering the playback after the page load with:

```
document.getElementById("movie").play();
```

But no dice.

Any thoughts on how I can get the movie to playback on the first page load?

Comment: Hi Kyle! Any luck with the issue? Dealing with exactly the same problem now.

Comment: I never did have any luck with that. And based on the lack of answers, I don't think most have either. :/